# UIButton.layer.cornerRadius doesn't exist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, properties, uibutton

I'm implementing a custom UIButton with minimal functionality. The .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface CustomButton : UIButton {
}
@end
```

I'm encountering a compilation error at line (A) in the .m file:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {

        CALayer *layer = [self layer];
        NSLog(@"layer=%@",layer);
        NSLog(@"delegate=%@",[layer delegate]);

#ifdef __IPHONE_3_0
        layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f; // (A) error: request for member 'cornerRadius' in something not a structure or union
#endif
    }
    return self;
}
```

If I comment out line (A), I get the following output:

```
2009-10-08 17:35:06.681 MyApp[2596:4e07] layer=<CALayer: 0x3cdf520>
2009-10-08 17:35:06.683 MyApp[2596:4e07] delegate=<CustomButton: 0x3cdaff0; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (9 212; 255 55); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x3cdf520>>
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/cornerRadius), CALayer should have a cornerRadius property. I'm using iPhone SDK 3.1 and even added an #ifdef to confirm this.

Can someone please show me where I've overlooked the obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Make sure you

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

into your header or implementation file.

Comment: If you mean "#import "CustomButton.h", I did that at the start of the .m file.

Comment: ugh. No, sorry, the formatting screwed things up. #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Ah! Finally! I've been unable to use cornerRadius for ages as I didn't know that. Cheers.

Comment: if you add an image on button , be sure you set cliptobounds = YES; button.imageview.layer.cornerradius = XX

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    Button.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    [Button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: This question was correctly answered years ago, your answer adds nothing.

Comment: Your question solved my problem, but my problem was not this question.. Still upvoting for your contribution. :)